# Graham-Rothschild via Hales-Jewett

Tags: additive-combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I am currently reading the recent preprint of Dodos, Kanellopoulos, Tyros, where the ambitiously short proof of Density Hales Jewett theorem is provided. The important ingredient is Graham-Rothschild theorem. The authors say that it follows from the HJ by some standard Ramsey arguments, but I can not find them myself, at least immediately. Is it written anywhere? Original paper of Graham and Rothschild looks too long for being used in "simple self-contained proof" of anything. Polymath's DHJ proof does not use GR at all, on first glance.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.4986.pdf

Comment: @Kristal, it is exactly the paper I mean. Now I asked its authors directly and got a satisfactory answer with references.

Comment: Fedor: Could you share the answer you got? I am struggling with the same exact problem.

Comment: "The coloring result we use is indeed a special case of the
Graham-Rothchild theorem. We do not say much about it in the paper,
since this staff is considered to be part of the folklore. In any case,here are some references.

1) A simple and self-contained proof of the full Graham-Rothchild
theorem can be found in: H. J. Promel and B. Voigt, Graham-Rothschild parameter sets, "Mathematics of Ramsey Theory", Springer-Verlag, Berlin (1990), 113-149.See in particular, Section 4, page 128.

2) Another excellent reference is: R. McCutcheon, Elemental Methods in Ergodic Ramsey Theory, Lect"

Answer (score 3):

In Randall - McCutcheon's book "Elemental methods in ergodic Ramsey theory" a stronger version of GR's theorem  is prooved about block subspaces (theorem 2.4.1). The only theorems you need in order to proove it is Hales-Jewett and Folkman's theorem (about finite unions which you can proove using  Hales - Jewett theorem again).

Another proof is given in Graham - Rothschild -Spencer book about Ramsey theory using HJ and linear algebra.

Comment: Thanks! Probably, linear algebra is used for linear algebraic version of Graham-Rothschild, while we need a combinatorial one?

Comment: You're wright. If you want a proof for the combinatorial version of the thorem it is the one a mentioned in the first place.